# SQLiteAsyncConnection UpdateWithChildren not available

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net-extensions

I am trying to implement a OneToMany relationship inside my PCL using SQLite.net.  I have the async extensions package (SQLiteNetExtensions.Async) and I am basing the code on the example found in  https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions.  I am using SQLiteAsyncConnection but the UpdateWithChildren method does not seem to be available, only with SQLiteConnection.

```
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Async;
using SQLite.Net.Interop;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;

private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;
public ActivityRepository(ISQLitePlatform platform, string dbPath)
{
    var connectionFactory = new Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock>(() => new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(platform, new SQLiteConnectionString(dbPath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: true)));
    conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(connectionFactory);
}
public void method(object object) {
    conn.UpdateWithChildren(object); --function not available
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `SQLiteAsyncConnection`, you have to use the [async Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions.Async/), `SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync.Extensions` namespace and async versions of all the methods:

```
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Async;
using SQLite.Net.Interop;
using SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync.Extensions;

private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;
public ActivityRepository(ISQLitePlatform platform, string dbPath)
{
    var connectionFactory = new Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock>(() => new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(platform, new SQLiteConnectionString(dbPath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: true)));
    conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(connectionFactory);
}
public Task method(object object) {
    return conn.UpdateWithChildrenAsync(object);
}
```

Please note that all async methods return a `Task` that must be awaited or returned.

Comment: Thanks, I had the async package installed I just wasn't using the UpdateWithChildrenAsync method.