# How to do the CRUD operations for a table with a foreign key with SQLiteNet-Extensions

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net-extensions, sqlite-net-pcl

I am using sqlite-net-pcl with the SqLiteNetExtensions for a foreign key. I have this two tables ( not sure if they are written correctly) an agenda can contain many Tasks, my question is how do i write the CRUD methods to  add/delete/load my tasks in my agenda, i am not sure how this work when you have a foreign key ?

I tried to understand the documentation : https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/

Without any success, what i don't get is that the WithChildren methods doesn't seem to be recognized unless the `database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);` doesn't work for the SqliteNetExtensions.
Note that the CRUD methods for my agenda is working but i am trying to implement the CRUD methods for the tasks. Also in my agenda method called GetAgendaAsync() i am not sure if this will load the data with the tasks already or i have to do something to add the tasks to it when loaded ?

Thank you, i am kinda lost with this.

**Agenda.cs in the Models folder**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using Calculette.Database;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
    [Table("Agenda")]
    public class Agenda
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; } 
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
}
```

**Tasks.cs in Models folder**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
[Table("Task")]
public class Tasks
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Agenda))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne]
    public Agenda Agenda { get; set; }
    
}
```

**AgendaDatabase.cs in the Database folder ( all my operation currently for the Agenda table)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using Calculette.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Calculette.ViewModel;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;

public class AgendaDatabase
{
    
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public AgendaDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
       
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<Agenda>().Wait();
database.CreateTableAsync<Tasks>().Wait();
    


    }

    // Get all agenda
    public Task<List<Agenda>> GetAgendasAsync()
    {

        return database.Table<Agenda>().ToListAsync();
    }

    // Get specific agenda
    public Task<Agenda> GetAgendaAsync(int id)
    {
        return database.Table<Agenda>()
                        .Where(i => i.ID == id)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    // Insert new agenda (save)
    public Task<int> SaveAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
    {
        if (agenda.ID != 0)
        {
            return database.UpdateAsync(agenda);
        }
        else
        {
            return database.InsertAsync(agenda);
        }
    }
    
    //Delete specific agenda
    public Task<int> DeleteAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync(agenda);
    }
    public Task<int> AddAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
    {
        return database.InsertAsync(agenda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to be using the Async version of SQLiteNetExtensions and importing the async namespace. Otherwise the extensions methods will not work because they are extending the standard synchronous version.

Comment: what what is that namespace ? im not even sure it's written in the doc haha. Also would you mind helping out with a code example, im new to this and it's hard to understand with just words haha thanks !

Comment: Sure, there are some code samples in the test folder of the project:
https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/Tests/IntegrationTests/Tests/RecursiveReadAsyncTests.cs
Or check other answers in this very same site like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37811309/469218

Comment: Ok thanks adding this : using SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync.Extensions; made me able to use WithChildren.  Now correct me if i am wrong but to intialize both of my tables i would leave the GetAgendasAsync() method up there ( it gets all the agendas), then i would create an other method to get all the taks but like that ?         public Task<List<Tasks>> GetAllTasks()
        {

            return database.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<Tasks>();

        }  Thanks

Comment: Yes, that would should do it. As a side note, I'm asuming your code is just a sample, but just in case: initializing the database in a class constructor is usually a bad practice.